# How do I permit only one particular user to login to active admin?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I have a application that have a lot of users and among them only one is super user. I want to use this super user account to use active admin and other users will use my custom admin dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a boolean "admin" attribute on your users and then check for that attribute using a custom AuthorizationAdapter.

Check this part of the documentation for further information: http://activeadmin.info/docs/13-authorization-adapter.html